# Which region would work best to display what I need on Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, apex

I am trying to make a page that returns header information for all employees, but when an employee is clicked it returns all details of that employee. I have drawn up an example that may better help explain what I am trying to do. I am curious on what type of regions I should choose, and if there is an example application that I could use to base mine off of. Thanks!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMfjH.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the wizard:

- create page
- report
- **report with form**

It'll create two pages:

- an interactive report (you'll use to view some info for all employees on the same page, as if they are in an Excel worksheet) and
- a form, which lets you show all details related to selected employee (which means that form can contain many more items than report)

Comment: Hello, I am running into a little issue. I still need the part where it derives some information on the header and shows the rest when clicked, but the information isn't being pulled from a table, it need to be pulled from a query. The query has to take in bind variables to get the output.

Comment: I presume you can create a **classic report** which would use that "query" you mentioned as its source.